# SQL interview question

Tags: sql

I got following question on an interview:
Which SQL mechanisms allow user to browse tables sequentially?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cursor is a good example - but I don't think you could really argue that  Cursors are truely a part of SQL - rather they just tend to come bolted in with procedural languages used on database servers - like pl/SQL and T-SQL.

You could also make an argument for Recordsets, Dynasets, DataTables and DataViews, but those aren't part of SQL itself either.

They might be referring to ORDER BY with a sequential field on the table, but if so, they've not phrased their question very well...

Martin.

Answer (score 2):

"CURSOR" might be the word that you should google for.

Comment: Are there any other than cursor machanisms ?
I got confused, because question was about 'mechanisms' not 'mechanism' :|

Comment: I guess Martin already answered that.